# How to unset environment variable in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkinsfile and the JAVA_HOME environment variable is already set when the process starts up. Unfortunately, this environment variable is being passed into my container when I run a script in `docker.inside` and is overriding the correct value of the environment variable that is already set in the image.

How do I unset an environment variable in a Jenkins script?

Answer (score 2):

I want to do the same thing but unfortunetely, I think that natively in jenkins, there is no unset() method in the EnvActionImpl class.

you should then just override the value with something like this:

```
env.VAULT_TOKEN = ''
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I think that in my case that would just leave me with my correct value replaced with a different wrong value.

Comment: In my case, this actually unsets the variable as requested by the OP.